# Traffic Bandwidth Issues

Tags: magento-1.9, robots.txt

I'm having several issues with my site, I checked AWStats and it is showing that robots have used 18gb bandwidth this month (usual for other months is 150mb).

I was told by my server hosts to alter the **robots.txt** file but it is still happening, I have tried blocking individual IP addresses but it is continuing. There have been 160,000 hits by the robot this month how can

Do I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems with bots because, unfortunately, "bad bots" don't always listen to robots.txt entries.  My solution was to block them via .htaccess, and it will vary between the different user agents, but the block below gives an example of what I used:

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>

    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^MJ12bot.*" bad_bot
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Sogou.*" bad_bot
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^BaiduSpider.*" bad_bot
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Yandex.*" bad_bot
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^SemrushBot.*" bad_bot

    <Limit GET POST PUT>
          Order Allow,Deny
          Allow from all
          Deny from env=bad_bot
    </Limit>
</IfModule>
```

There is also a great article by [InMotion Hosting](https://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/block-bots-with-htaccess.shtml) that goes into more detail, providing a few alternative directives that can work if you have different mods enabled in your environment and/or block by Referrer in addition to User-Agent.